# Serving Multiple TF Models in TF Serving and Creating Appropriate Client Request to Interact with Specific Model as per the Request

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensor

Can you please suggest any blog or tutorial which will help in Serving Multiple TF Models in TF Serving and Creating Appropriate Client Request to Interact with Specific Model as per the Request.

My Requirement:
1. I have to host multiple models in the tensorflow serving 
2. Client request comes for whatever model, only that would be worked upon

Let me brief you how I am trying to address this requirement:
1.I copied the required models in docker container
2.I have created the following config file which defines the models loaded in docker container:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "model1",
    base_path:  "<path to model1 saved in docker container>",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  },
  config: {
    name:  "model2",
    base_path:  "<path to model2 saved in docker container>",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

3.Next, while start the serving instead of defining individual model's bash path, I am 
providing the path to the config file inside docker container:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_config_file=<path to config file saved in docker container>
```

Now, where I am facing challenges are:
1.How to create/modify the client.py file for multiple models in one single client file.
2.What would be the format of the client request?

It will be very helpful to get any lead to solve the challenge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm dealing with similar issue of combining multiple model requests into single one requests on client side. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "create/modify the client.py file for multiple models in one single client file"?

You could specify model name and model version like this

```
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'model1'
request.model_spec.version.value = 1 # Or any other number you want
```